# Want to join two tables on primary key, display the results in one view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

```
IQueryable<Product> product = objContext.Set<Product>().Include(p => 
p.Categories.Name).Where(p => p.Id == 2);
```

As per the current view, I'm getting an error. It says add other model with their properties. i.e. to include Category model and corresponding Name property.

```
@model IEnumerable<>crudOneToMany.Models.Product>
```

using `viewmodel`, is it possible to join two tables?

**[View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxZZN.png)**

Error
A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'crudOneToMany.Models.Category' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Name'.

```
 public class Product  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string Name { get; set; }  
        public string Description { get; set; }  
        public int CategoryId { get; set; }  

        public virtual Category Categories { get; set; }  
    }


public class Category  
    {  
        public int Id { get; set; }  
        public string  Name { get; set; }  

        public ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }  
    }  


public class ProductDBContext : DbContext
    {
        public ProductDBContext()
            : base("ProductDBContext")
        {

        }

        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Category> Categories { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().HasRequired(o => o.Categories).WithMany(o => o.Products).HasForeignKey(o => o.CategoryId);
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes,`ViewModel's` whole purpose is for that. What is your issue ? Can you share your `viewmodel` and the way you have filled it ?

Comment: Check out now. thank you for your efforts

Comment: Don't you have `ViewModel` right now for the above scenario ? What kind of knowledge do you have about `viewmodel` ?

Comment: I dont have knowledge, saw few videos. I have to learn it from scratch

Comment: using viewmodel will it get solved? merging of two tables on primary key will be done?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the proposed `ViewModel` for you.

`ProductViewModel.cs`

```
public class ProductViewModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        [Required(ErrorMessage = "required")]
        public string ProductName { get; set; }
               
        public Category  Category  { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Category> Categories { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
.Include(p => p.Categories.Name)
```

Instead you should write `.Include(p => p.Categories)`
This means that in output there will be loaded Categories navigation collection to product.
`Name` is simple string property (is not navigation property so it should not be included)

Comment: Then how can he shows the `category list` on his view ? : http://i.stack.imgur.com/KxZZN.png

Comment: and what is the problem to create foreach(var item in Model.Categories)? If there would be code of view, i would change it, but i don't want to wrote whole view.